# outer while loop iterates fine but the inner while loop doesn't iterate

Tags: bash

This is my bash:

```
while read -r dedicated_ip
do
    while read -r details
    do
        while read -r plans
        do
            openstack_show=$(openstack show "$details")
            if [ "$(echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/External_Network network/ {print $5; exit}')" == "$dedicated_ip" ]
            then
                echo "$(echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/External_Network network/ {print $5; exit}') == $dedicated_ip"
                if [ "${HOSTNAME,,}" == 'hostnamea.my.domain.com' ] || [ "${HOSTNAME,,}" == 'hostnameb.my.domain.com' ]
                then
                    plan_name=$(echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/plan:original_name/ {$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' | sed -e 's|\|||g' | sed -e 's|  ||g' | sed -e 's|^ ||g' | sed -e 's| $||g')
                    echo "$(echo "$plan_name" | sed -e 's|ABPlan|Plan|g') == $plans"
                    break
                elif [ "${HOSTNAME,,}" == 'hostnamec.my.domain.com' ] || [ "${HOSTNAME,,}" == 'hostnamed.my.domain.com' ]
                then
                    plan_name=$(echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/plan:original_name/ {$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' | sed -e 's|\|||g' | sed -e 's|  ||g' | sed -e 's|^ ||g' | sed -e 's| $||g')
                    echo "$(echo $plan_name | sed -e 's|CDPlan|Plan|g') == $plans"
                    break
                fi
                break
            fi
        done < <(grep "name: '" products.yaml | sed -e "s|'||g" | sed -e 's|name: ||g')
    done < <(awk '{print $2}' details_list)
done < <(grep dedicated_ip products.yaml | awk '{print $2}')
```

Explanation of my code:

1. It iterates over a `yaml` file for IPs only, then runs `openstack show $details` for every ID of `details_list`.
2. Then it checks if the `External Network` of `details_list` equals to the match IP of `yaml` file, it then checks based on the hostname of the server, it replaces the plans name and checks if it matches with the `yaml` file.
3. If IP matches --> ip == ip, if plan matches --> plan == plan

But the issue is if `plan == plan` is not true in the output. I don't know how it checks and shows the two complete string match.

This is `products.yaml`:

```
dedicated_ip: 1.1.1.1
name: 'ABPlan BGP10'
dedicated_ip: 2.2.2.2
name: 'CDPlan BGP40'
dedicated_ip: 3.3.3.3
name: 'Plan BGP10'
```

This is `openstack show $details` (a sample of one hostname only):

```
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property                             | Value                                                                |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| External_Network network             | 1.1.1.1                                                              |
| hostname                             | some hostname of user                                                |
| vm_state                             | active                                                               |
| launched_at                          | 2023-05-02T13:42:32.000000                                           |
| plan:original_name                   | ABPlan BGP10                                                         |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is a sample of `details_list`:

```
| 0e562488-1b53-4198-8311-72e3f462c4d4 | hostname user1                      | ACTIVE  | -          | Running     | External_Network=1.1.1.1                                            |
| 0bf7bbaa-a750-462b-ab5c-dd137d2f84c0 | hostnameUserB                       | ACTIVE  | -          | Running     | External_Network=2.2.2.2                                            |
| 0bf7sbaa-a750-4p2b-az5c-dd137d2f84c0 | hostnameUserC                       | ACTIVE  | -          | Running     | External_Network=3.3.3.3                                            |
```

This is the output when I run my bash:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
2.2.2.2 == 2.2.2.2
CDPlan BGP40 == Plan BGP10
3.3.3.3 == 3.3.3.3
ABPlan BGP40 == Plan BGP10
```

This is the issue for `plans`, when the second part of equality doesn't iterate. I mean at each iteration and after the plan names ==, the second part is always `Plan BGP10`.

Expected output:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
2.2.2.2 == 2.2.2.2
CDPlan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
3.3.3.3 == 3.3.3.3
ABPlan BGP60 == Plan BGP60
```

Comment: You never need grep or sed when you're using awk. All those pipelines that include awk could each just be a call to awk alone. The whole script should be an awk script, though, not a shell script. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @EdMorton thanks a lot. Regarding `awk` and `sed`, I know it requires to be better, but that's not the issue currently. Regarding other comment, I edited question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254720/discussion-between-saeed-and-ed-morton).

Comment: @EdMorton if that's okay, I may edit the question completely soon. I'll test your answer and reply is worked.

Comment: Don't completely change a question after you got answers. Accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new question if your original one wasn't what you intended to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell `openstack show "$details"` shouldn't become part of an awk script but instead should stay being called in a loop in the shell script that calls awk and, if so, then one possibility would be for your shell script to look like this (using any POSIX awk):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r _ details _; do
    openstack show "$details"
done < details_list |
awk -v host="${HOSTNAME,,}" -F'[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' '
    NR==FNR {
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
        if ( sub(/^dedicated_ip:[[:space:]]*/,"") ) {
            ip = $0
        }
        else if ( sub(/^name:[[:space:]]*/,"") ) {
            gsub(/\047/,"")
            ip2name[ip] = $0
        }
        next
    }
    $2 == "External_Network network" {
        ip = $3
    }
    $2 == "plan:original_name" {
        plan_name = $3
        show_name = ip2name[ip]
        print host, ip, plan_name, show_name
        if ( (host == "hostnamea.my.domain.com") || (host == "hostnameb.my.domain.com") ) {
            print "a or b"
        }
        else if ( (host == "hostnamec.my.domain.com") || (host == "hostnamed.my.domain.com") ) {
            print "c or d"
        }
        else {
            print "other"
        }
    }
' products.yaml -
```

Modify around the `print` statements to do whatever comparisons and printing you actually want.

Whether it's best to read `products.yaml` first and then compare the `openstack` output to it (as I do above) or vice-versa depends on some details that aren't clear in your question such as what to do with IP addresses from one that don't appear in the other. It's trivial to just flip the `NR==FNR { next }` vs the rest of the script logic or add an `END` section to process unmatched IP addresses if necessary though.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I'll make my question more simple and ask a new question. I know it is not much easy to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes you are using,

```
echo "$(echo "$openstack_show" (...)
```

while other times you  are using

```
echo "$(echo "openstack_show" (...)
```

This is vastly different. This looks to me like a major technical flaw in the script.

---

*semi-relevant opinion*

*I find this script too complicated and convoluted. Try stating the problem in natural language and see what kind of solution people come up with. That may be a better learning experience then what you are currently doing*

Comment: Can you please change `command_show` to `openstack_show`? I edited my question to avoid mixing `command` with UNIX utility

Comment: The OP accidentally removed the `$`s in an edit, that issue wasn't part of the question and they'll hopefully fix that soon, see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796603/outer-while-loop-iterates-fine-but-the-inner-while-loop-doesnt-iterate/76797699#comment135390051_76796603).

Comment: @Saeed No. You can edit it. I don't understand the problem. So no sense in trying to improve the question...

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in both of these 'if' conditions,you're comparing the variable `$plan_name` with `$plans`,however, it seems like the value of `$plan_name` isn't getting updated with each iteration,so I think I have a suggestion that might help improve your approach:

```
while read -r dedicated_ip
do
    while read -r details
    do
        while read -r plans
        do
            openstack_show=$(openstack show "$details")
            if [ "$(echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/External_Network network/ {print $5; exit}')" == "$dedicated_ip" ]
            then
                echo "$(echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/External_Network network/ {print $5; exit}') == $dedicated_ip"
                if [ "${HOSTNAME,,}" == 'hostnamea.my.domain.com' ] || [ "${HOSTNAME,,}" == 'hostnameb.my.domain.com' ]
                then
                    plan_name=$(echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/plan:original_name/ {$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' | sed -e 's|\|||g' | sed -e 's|  ||g' | sed -e 's|^ ||g' | sed -e 's| $||g')
                    plan_name_modified=$(echo "$plan_name" | sed -e 's|ABPlan|Plan|g')
                    echo "$plan_name_modified == $plans"
                    break
                elif [ "${HOSTNAME,,}" == 'hostnamec.my.domain.com' ] || [ "${HOSTNAME,,}" == 'hostnamed.my.domain.com' ]
                then
                    plan_name=$(echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/plan:original_name/ {$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' | sed -e 's|\|||g' | sed -e 's|  ||g' | sed -e 's|^ ||g' | sed -e 's| $||g')
                    plan_name_modified=$(echo "$plan_name" | sed -e 's|CDPlan|Plan|g')
                    echo "$plan_name_modified == $plans"
                    break
                fi
                break
            fi
        done < <(grep "name: '" products.yaml | sed -e "s|'||g" | sed -e 's|name: ||g')
    done < <(awk '{print $2}' details_list)
done < <(grep dedicated_ip products.yaml | awk '{print $2}')
```

so as you see,I've added a new variable called `plan_name_modified` that allows you to adjust the value of `$plan_name` before comparing it with `$plans`!

Comment: The `$plan_name` is exactly the same as `$plan_name_modified`

Comment: no not same,the variable `$plan_name` is assigned the value extracted from the output of the command `echo "$openstack_show" | awk '/plan:original_name/ {$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' | sed -e 's|\|||g' | sed -e 's| ||g' | sed -e 's|^ ||g' | sed -e 's| $||g'`.on the other hand, the variable $plan_name_modified is assigned the value of $plan_name after performing a substitution using the sed command `sed -e 's|ABPlan|Plan|g'` or `sed -e 's|CDPlan|Plan|g'` depending on the condition!so, `$plan_name_modified` is a modified version of $plan_name, where certain patterns are replaced with the word "Plan"!

Comment: Thanks, but yes they're the same my friend. The `$plan_name` is like `CDPlan BGP10` and it is replaced by `Plan BGP10` in my version, but in yours, the `$plan_name_modified` is the same exactly as mine.

Comment: Dear @EdMorton , could you please kindly share your opinion with us as an expert? Thank you for your kindness and generosity.

Comment: I think that all @Saeed is trying to say is that the output of their `echo "$(echo $plan_name | sed -e 's|CDPlan|Plan|g') == $plans"` is the same as the output of your `plan_name_modified=$(echo "$plan_name" | sed -e 's|CDPlan|Plan|g');
                    echo "$plan_name_modified == $plans"` which would be true. So, best I can tell, it's wrong to say that "The $plan_name is exactly the same as $plan_name_modified" but it would be correct to say the output is the same whether you have an intermediate variable or not.