# bash while loop does not work as expected

Tags: bash, awk

I know technically, it may work as it is and it is the expected by the `bash` language, but it's not what I expected and wrote.

I tried to make everything as simple as possible.

This is `fileA`:

```
+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| Name               | Status    | Networks   | Image     | Plans      |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| HostName A         | PAUSED    | IP=1.1.1.1 | Ubuntu20  | Plan BGP40 |
| An other hostname  | ACTIVE    | IP=2.2.2.2 | Ubuntu20  | Plan BGP30 |
| final.destination  | REBOOTING | IP=3.3.3.3 | Debian11  | Plan BGP10 |
| no problem         | ACTIVE    | IP=4.4.4.4 | Centos7   | Plan BGP90 |
| no problem         | ACTIVE    | IP=6.6.6.6 | Ubuntu22  | Plan BGP60 |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

This is `fileB`:

```
dedicated_ip: 1.1.1.1
name: 'Plan BGP40'
dedicated_ip: 2.2.2.2
name: 'Plan BGP30'
dedicated_ip: 3.3.3.3
name: 'Plan BGP10'
dedicated_ip: 4.4.4.4
name: 'Plan BGP90'
dedicated_ip: 5.5.5.5
name: 'Plan BGP20'
dedicated_ip: 6.6.6.6
name: 'Plan BGP100'
```

All IPs exist in `fileA` should exist in `fileB`, but the IPs in `fileB` can be not presented in `fileA`, so that's OK if IP `5.5.5.5` doesn't exist in the table above.

This is my bash script:

```
while read -r ips_file_a
do
    while read -r plans_file_a
    do
        while read -r ips_file_b
        do
            while read -r plans_file_b
            do
                if [ "$ips_file_a" == "$ips_file_b" ]
                then
                    if [ "$plans_file_a" == "$plans_file_b" ]
                    then
                        echo "$ips_file_a == $ips_file_b"
                        echo "$plans_file_a == $plans_file_b"
                    fi
                fi
            done < <(awk '{ if ( $1 ~ /name/ ) { print $2, $3  } }' fileB | sed -e "s|'||g") # print plans and then remove single quote
        done < <(awk '{ if ( $1 ~ /dedicated_ip/ ) { print $2  } }' fileB) # print IPs
    done < <(awk -v d="Plans" 'BEGIN{FS="[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*"; idx=0} FNR==2{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (d==$i) idx=i; next} NR>1 {print $idx}' fileA | awk 'NF') # to print only Plans and then remove empty lines
done < <(awk -v d="Networks" 'BEGIN{FS="[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*"; idx=0} FNR==2{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (d==$i) idx=i; next} NR>1 {print $idx}' fileA | awk 'NF') # to print only IPs and then remove empty lines
```

This is the current output:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
2.2.2.2 == 2.2.2.2
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
3.3.3.3 == 3.3.3.3
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
4.4.4.4 == 4.4.4.4
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
```

I tried playing with changing the order of `while` loops but I either get the above output or the following:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP30 == Plan BGP30
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP90 == Plan BGP90
# then four times for each IP with four different plan names
```

There's an issue with my current output. I set `set -x` and see that after both IPs and Plans are equal, it continues again the loop with that IP. For example, if IP `1.1.1.1` and plan `Plan BGP10` are matched, it continues to check if `1.1.1.1 == 2.2.2.2` and the plan also `Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP30` as an example, which takes more time and does not exit when the `if` clause is True.

This is the expected output:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
2.2.2.2 == 2.2.2.2
Plan BGP30 == Plan BGP30
3.3.3.3 == 3.3.3.3
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
4.4.4.4 == 4.4.4.4
Plan BGP90 == Plan BGP90
```

**Update 1**

The `fileA` contains that for example `serverA` has these VMs.

The `fileB` is an output from my website that my clients are paying based on their plans.

I want to check if the client of IP `1.1.1.1` is really using `Plan BGP40` or not. Suppose client paid for an upgrade in the website to have `Plan BGP90`, but my website didn't connect to `serverA`, so upgrade didn't happen.

Suppose the above example, that client paid to have a bigger plan but is still using the old one. Or even client is paying for a smaller plan but, but in fact is using bigger plan.

I want to check this to find if there are issues like this.

**Update 2**

I added IP `6.6.6.6` in both files. Now this client is paying for `Plan BGP100` but his server's resources are `Plan BGP60`. So, he's paying for the big plan but in fact his resources are not `BGP60`.

This is an example of an issue. But in the expected output, the IP `6.6.6.6` will not be printed. I'll find those IPs which are not printed later.

Comment: I have a suspicion that you have already asked this question several times and always deleted it.

Comment: @Cyrus yes, but I had another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796603/outer-while-loop-iterates-fine-but-the-inner-while-loop-doesnt-iterate which was too complicated in my opinion and as it has answers, I don't intend to offend to remove the question and remove the answers. If I edit that question, then the answers will become meaningless.

Comment: You've provided your code, then described the code, but you haven't told us what you're trying to accomplish in 'simple english'; whether you're trying to debug your code, or get a different set of (workable) code, we need a clear description of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: it seems (to me) that the general issue is that you need to process the lines from `fileB` in pairs, but your code is processing each line separately, hence the reason you're coming up with combinations of mismatched ips and names

Comment: is this as simple as: join `fileA/IP/Plans` to `fileB/dedicated_ip/name` and if there's a match then display the `dedicated_ip/name` pair from `fileB`?

Comment: @markp-fuso I edited the question with an explanation.

Comment: I don't understand the objective of printing 'ip == ip' and 'plan == plan'; could you have an accepted scenario where the ip's are different (eg, `1.1.1.1 == 2.2.2.2`) or the plans are different (eg, `Plan BGP90 == Plan XX123`)?

Comment: your latest update is still as clear as mud (to me); join on ip and if the plans are the same then print the ip/plan pair? what if there's an ip match but the plans are different .... print a different message? print nothing? regardless, please update the sample inputs to show an example where the plans do not match for a given ip (ie, right now all 4 sets of matching ips also have matching plans ... so we can't see what's supposed to happen if ip's match but the associated plans are different)

Comment: @markp-fuso I updated again. I'm sorry I didn't understand what you mean by joining `fileA/IP/Plans` to `fileB/dedicated_ip/name`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254737/discussion-between-saeed-and-markp-fuso).

Comment: so based on your 2nd update ... "only print the ip/plan names where the ip ***AND*** plan match between `fileA` and `fileB`" ?

Comment: join ==>  compare `fileA/IP` to `fileB/dedicated_ip` .... compare `fileA/Plans` to `fileB/name`

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, that's right. Only print if both IP and Plans match.

Comment: @markp-fuso I changed the order or `while` loop, Now each IP is printed four times with four different plans `1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1`, then `Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40`, `1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1` and `Plan BGP30 == Plan BGP30`.

Comment: changing the order of the `while` loops won't matter since you're still not processing the lines from `fileB` in pairs (ie, you're losing the relationship between the matched `dedicated_ip` and `name` entries)

Comment: Regarding "I know ... it is the expected by the bash language," - no, you should never write such nested loops in bash for processing text, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons. Please take another look at [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76797638/1745001) because THAT is the way to do something like this in bash and so should be your starting point for other similar problems.

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks. I think I don't understand the phrase `... in pairs`. I should study and google more, and also thanks a lot the answer. I'm reading the comments of your code.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks a lot. Pardon, but it's a bit early for me to understand all of these answers completely and writing them myself later. But that's my starting point to see the codes of experts like your and `markp-fuso` and try to understand that.

Comment: *`pairs`* => as in pairs of lines, as in ... *you need to look at the data from fileB in terms of pairs of lines* ... or ... *you need to keep the dedicated_ip line together with the associated name line*

Comment: your latest/3rd update is now changing the essence of the original question; instead of modifying the current question you should ask a new question; I have rolled back your latest update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- join the two files based on `fileA/IP == fileB/dedicated_ip` and `fileA/Plans - fileB/name`
- if there's an exact match on both the ip and plan/name then print the desired output

While this type of processing could be done in `bash`, it will require matching individual lines from `FileA` against *pairs* of lines from `fileB` ... doable, but a bit convoluted.  And since the current code already includes a half dozen `awk` scripts, we can make our lives much simpler (and the code will be a *lot* more efficient) if we just use a single `awk` script to do everything.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v qt="'" '
                # 1st file

FNR==NR         { if (FNR>=4 && !($0 ~ /-------/)) {                     # only look at lines from FNR>=4 and ignore any lines with "--------------"
                     split($0,a,"[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*")           # split on "|" with possible leading/trailing white space; a[4] will contain the "IP=a.b.c.d" string and a[6] will contain the plan name
                     split(a[4],b,"=")                                   # split the "IP=a.b.c.d" string; b[2] will contain the ip address
                     plans[b[2]] = a[6]                                  # save our data: plans[ip]="plan name"
                  }
                  next
                }

                # 2nd file

/dedicated_ip:/ { ip = $2 }                                              # save the ip address
/name:/         { split($0,c,qt)                                         # split the line on a single quote; c[2] will contain plan name
                  if (ip in plans && c[2] == plans[ip])                  # if current ip is an index in plans[] array, and current plan name matches the plan name stored in plans[ip] ...
                     printf "%s == %s\n%s == %s\n", ip, ip, c[2], c[2]   # print the desired output
                }
' fileA fileB
```

This generates:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
2.2.2.2 == 2.2.2.2
Plan BGP30 == Plan BGP30
3.3.3.3 == 3.3.3.3
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
4.4.4.4 == 4.4.4.4
Plan BGP90 == Plan BGP90
```

Comment: @Saeed notice the similar structure of this answer vs [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796603/outer-while-loop-iterates-fine-but-the-inner-while-loop-doesnt-iterate/76797638#76797638) because it's the right approach for the kinds of problem you are posting.

Comment: @EdMorton I may need to mix your answer with `markp-fuso` because of replacing the plan names in previous question.

Comment: @Saeed it's good that you have a couple of similar solutions to slightly different problems now to learn from and build upon. Good luck!

Comment: @markp-fuso can you help me a bit for a replacement in `awk`? I'll edit the question soon and add my failed attempts.

Comment: @Saeed [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum. If you have a followup question then just ask a new question.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, I asked a new one last night

Answer (score 3):

OP's current answer really isn't (100%) `bash` if simply because of all the calls to `awk`.  But if OP really, really needs to do this in `bash` (while also using `awk` to preprocess the files) ...

Re-using some of the `awk` code from my other answer to pre-process the two files:

```
while IFS="|" read -r ip1 plan1
do
    while IFS="|" read -r ip2 plan2
    do
        if [[ "${ip1}" = "${ip2}" && "${plan1}" = "${plan2}" ]]
        then
            printf "%s == %s\n%s == %s\n" "${ip1}" "${ip2}" "${plan1}" "${plan2}"
          # break             # uncomment for slight performance gain if there can be at most one match between files
        fi
    done < <(awk -v qt="'" 'BEGIN { OFS="|" } /dedicated_ip:/ { ip = $2 } /name:/ { split($0,c,qt); print ip,c[2] }' fileB)
done < <(awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*"; OFS="|" } NR>=4 && $4 ~ /IP/ { split($4,a,"="); print a[2],$6 }' fileA)
```

Where:

- the objective is to use `awk` to pre-process each file and generate ouputs of the format `ip|plan_name`
- **NOTE:** for `fileB` we consolidate pairs of lines (`dedicated_ip` + `name`) to generate a single line of output
- then use nested `while` loops to compare the two sets of data
- keep in mind this still isn't very efficient (certainly not as efficient as code written in a different language, eg, the other answer written entirely in `awk`)

This generates:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
2.2.2.2 == 2.2.2.2
Plan BGP30 == Plan BGP30
3.3.3.3 == 3.3.3.3
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
4.4.4.4 == 4.4.4.4
Plan BGP90 == Plan BGP90
```

---

As mentioned, this isn't really a (100%) `bash` script because of the reliance on `awk`.

For a (100%) `bash` solution I'd probably start with two standalone loops that pre-process the 2 files, populating some arrays with the processed results, then a 3rd loop would scroll through one array looking for matches in the 2nd array.

In pseudo code:

```
while read -r line
do
     # for lines of interest split $line apart and store in array f1[ip]=plan
done < fileA

while read -r line
do
     # for lines of interest split $line apart and store in array f2[ip]=plan
     # keep in mind that you'll need to process $line's in pairs to build the array entry
done < fileB

for ndx in "${f1[@]}"
do
    if [[ "${f1[$ndx]}" = ${f2[$ndx]}" ]]
    then
        printf "%s == %s\n%s == %s\n" "${ndx}" "${ndx}" "${f1[$ndx]}" "${f2[$ndx]}}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, but as you stated in this answer, the `awk` solution is much more faster than the `bash` solution.