# replacing variable value in a loop in awk doesn't replace

Tags: bash, awk

Based on [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76806610) and based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76806610/bash-while-loop-does-not-work-as-expected#comment135406322_76806610) of [markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366100/markp-fuso), I intend to replace some plan names.

`fileA`:

```
+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| Name               | Status    | Networks   | Image     | Plans      |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| HostName A         | PAUSED    | IP=1.1.1.1 | Ubuntu20  | Plan BGP40 |
| An other hostname  | ACTIVE    | IP=2.2.2.2 | Ubuntu20  | Plan BGP30 |
| final.destination  | REBOOTING | IP=3.3.3.3 | Debian11  | Plan BGP10 |
| no problem         | ACTIVE    | IP=4.4.4.4 | Centos7   | Plan BGP90 |
| no problem         | ACTIVE    | IP=6.6.6.6 | Ubuntu22  | Plan BGP60 |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

`fileB`:

```
dedicated_ip: 1.1.1.1
name: 'AIPlan BGP40'
dedicated_ip: 2.2.2.2
name: 'IAPlan BGP30'
dedicated_ip: 3.3.3.3
name: 'Plan BGP10'
dedicated_ip: 4.4.4.4
name: 'Plan BGP90'
dedicated_ip: 5.5.5.5
name: 'Plan BGP20'
dedicated_ip: 6.6.6.6
name: 'PVPlan BGP100'
```

It should act like this:

- if hostname == `serverA` or hostname == `serverB`, then replace `AIPlan` with `Plan`, and also replace `IAPlan` with `Plan` (the `serverA` or `serverB` may have some old plan names of these two)
- if hostname == `serverC` or hostname == `serverD`, then replace `PVPlan` with `Plan`

This is my attempt:

```
awk -v qt="'" -v host="${HOSTNAME,,}" '
                # 1st file

FNR==NR         { if (FNR>=4 && !($0 ~ /-------/)) {                    # only look at lines from FNR>=4 and ignore any lines with "--------------"
                    split($0,a,"[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*")           # split on "|" with possible leading/trailing white space; a[4] will contain the "IP=a.b.c.d" string and a[6] will contain the plan name
                    split(a[4],b,"=")                                   # split the "IP=a.b.c.d" string; b[2] will contain the ip address
                    plans[b[2]] = a[6]                                  # save our data: plans[ip]="plan name"
                }
                next
                }

                # 2nd file

/dedicated_ip:/ { ip = $2 }                                              # save the ip address
/name:/         { split($0,c,qt)                                         # split the line on a single quote; c[2] will contain plan name
                    if ( (host == "desktop-9pr0r3p") || (host == "serverB")  || (host == "serverA") ) {
                        if (ip in plans && c[2] == plans[ip])                  # if current ip is an index in plans[] array, and current plan name matches the plan name stored in plans[ip] ...
                            ip=gsub(/AIPlan/,"Plan")
                            printf "%s == %s\n%s == %s\n", ip, ip, c[2], c[2]   # print the desired output
                    }
                    else if ( (host == "hostnamec.my.domain.com") || (host == "hostnamed.my.domain.com") ) {
                        print "c or d"
                    }
                    else {
                        print "other"
                    }
                }
' fileA fileB
```

Note: I didn't complete `else if`, because I have issue in the `if` clause block itself and I think the method of `if` is the same to use in `else if`.

This is my current output:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
AIPlan BGP40 == AIPlan BGP40
0 == 0
Plan BGP30 == Plan BGP30
0 == 0
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
0 == 0
Plan BGP90 == Plan BGP90
5.5.5.5 == 5.5.5.5
Plan BGP20 == Plan BGP20
```

Expected output is:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
2.2.2.2 == 2.2.2.2
Plan BGP30 == Plan BGP30
3.3.3.3 == 3.3.3.3
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
4.4.4.4 == 4.4.4.4
Plan BGP90 == Plan BGP90
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that you have already asked this question several times.

Comment: @Cyrus I asked a new question because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76806610/bash-while-loop-does-not-work-as-expected#comment135406322_76806610.

Comment: The return value of `gsub()` is the number of replacements made. So `ip=gsub(/AIPlan/,"Plan")` sets `ip` to the number of replacements. It doesn't hold the IP address any more.

Comment: BTW, your indentation suggests that you expect the `printf()` to be conditionalized by `if`. But since you didn't put `{}` around the `if` body, only the `gsub` line is conditional.

Comment: @Barmar yes sir, you're right. I didn't notice that. But I get another error when I change `ip=...` to `plans=...`: `awk: cmd. line:18: (FILENAME=fileB FNR=4) fatal: attempt to use array `plans' in a scalar context`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I want `gsub` line be in conditional based on what is the hostname.

Comment: Why do you think you need to assign the result of `gsub()` to a variable?

Comment: The gsub line is already conditional. It's the `printf` that isn't.

Comment: If you do want to assign it, use a new variable, not one of your existing variables. `plans` is the array indexed by IP.

Comment: @Barmar regarding why, I think I need to assign that to print the correct value.

Comment: gsub changes the fields it operates on in-place.

Comment: Are you trying to get the string with the replaced value? `gsub()` modifies the string in place, it doesn't return the updated string.

Comment: So the replacement is in `$0`.

Comment: @Barmar `Are you trying to get the string with the replaced value?`, yes.

Comment: `new = c[2]; gsub(/AIPlan/, "Plan", new); print c[2], "==", new;`

Comment: @Barmar the output is now `AIPlan BGP40 == AIPlan BGP40`. I replaced the line I added `ip=gsub...` with your code but I'm seeing this output.

Comment: _if `hostname == serverA`_: there is nothing like `hostname` or `serverA` in your question. Please edit it and provide consistent examples.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet that's in my question, sir. I need to replace string based on the hostname.

Comment: So, please edit your question and change the column header of your example table such that one column is named `hostname` and contains at least one row where the value is `serverA`. Then update your expected output accordingly. When asking questions here please try to provide easy to cut-and-paste examples such that those who try to help you don't have to guess, edit your input example, or imagine what your expected output should be for the input example you provide. Help them to help you.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet there's no header like `hostname`. It means the hostname of the server, which is usually FQDN.

Comment: So, please edit your question and instead of referring to `hostname` in your text, refer to an **existing** column header of your example table. Is it `Name`, `Status`, `Networks`, `Image`, `Plans`, something else? Same for `serverA`, please use an **existing** cell content of your table or change the content of your table such that at least one cell contains `serverA`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet the hostname is not like that. For example, my computer's name is `Desktop-Saeed 3456`,  and there another Linux server which name is `servera.domain.com`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet it looks like some possible typos by the OP; the script starts with `-v host="${HOSTNAME,,}"` and does reference `host` in some conditionals but unfortunately OP also refers to this variable as `hostname` (instead of `host`) in the description; OP also appears to be mixing sample hostnames: in the description are generalized names `server[ABCD]` but in the code is a mix of general names (`server[AB]`) and actual names (`desktop-9pr0r3p`, `hostnamec.my.domain.com`); it appears (to me) that all of this 'hostname' talk refers to an `awk` variable and not a data column (header)

Comment: @markp-fuso yes you're right. I didn't notice that. I meant `host` as it's a variable in my `awk` attempts which is actually your code. Thanks for correcting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- in `fileA` the plan name *always* starts with the string `Plan`
- in `fileB` the plan name starts with a string that *ends* with the string `Plan` but may also have a prefix (eg, `AI`, `IA`, `PV`)
- the objective is to insure all plan names (from `fileB`) start with the string `Plan`

**NOTE:** OP's current code attempts to apply a similar change when `c[2] == plans[ip]`, but I'm guessing OP really means to apply the change when the two plans names are *not* the same, ie, OP really means `c[2] != plans[ip]`.

While we could try to match on various hardcoded prefixes (eg, `AI`, `IA`, `PV`) I'm thinking it may be easier to just replace/overwrite the first string in a plan name (from `fileB`) with the string `Plan`.

Making a couple tweaks to OP's current code:

```
awk -v qt="'" -v host="desktop-9pr0r3p" '
FNR==NR         { if (FNR>=4 && !($0 ~ /-------/)) {
                    split($0,a,"[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*")
                    split(a[4],b,"=")
                    plans[b[2]] = a[6]
                }
                next
                }

/dedicated_ip:/ { ip = $2 }
/name:/         { split($0,c,qt)

                  sub(/^[^[:space:]]+/,"Plan",c[2])             #### NEW LINE: replace the leading string with "Plan"

                  if ( (host == "desktop-9pr0r3p") || (host == "serverB")  || (host == "serverA") ) {
                     if (ip in plans && c[2] == plans[ip])

                          # ip=gsub(/AIPlan/,"Plan")            #### REMOVE LINE

                            printf "%s == %s\n%s == %s\n", ip, ip, c[2], c[2]
                  }
                  else if ( (host == "hostnamec.my.domain.com") || (host == "hostnamed.my.domain.com") ) {
                          print "c or d"
                  }
                  else { print "other" }
                }
' fileA fileB
```

Where:

- instead of conditionally trying to determine when to apply a change to the (`fileB`) plan name how about we ...
- go ahead and make sure all (`fileB`) plan names start with `Plan` ...
- `sub(/^[^[:space:]]+/,"Plan",c[2])` - replace the leading non-space string in `c[2]` (`fileB` plan name) with the string `Plan` and ...
- the pre-existing conditional (`if (ip in plans && c[2] == plans[ip])`) remains the same

This generates:

```
1.1.1.1 == 1.1.1.1
Plan BGP40 == Plan BGP40
2.2.2.2 == 2.2.2.2
Plan BGP30 == Plan BGP30
3.3.3.3 == 3.3.3.3
Plan BGP10 == Plan BGP10
4.4.4.4 == 4.4.4.4
Plan BGP90 == Plan BGP90
```

Comment: Thanks, but the replaces is better to be based on hostname and the ifs I tried to have. I don't need to replace any string with `Plan`, but it should be based on hostname. Could you please edit that?

Comment: are you saying the 3rd assumption (*`all plan names from fileB should start with Plan`*) is incorrect? the expected output does not show any `c or d` / `other` strings but instead converts all plan names to start with `Plan` (which is what my code does); your code only tests for `AIPlan` so how do you end up removing not only `AI` but also `IA` and `PV` in the expected output?  based solely on the provided samples it looks like you want to insure all plan names start with `Plan` .... so instead of adding a lot code with a list of hardcoded prefixes (`AI` `IA` `PV`) I just process all entries

Comment: there's nothing keeping you from taking this code (which generates exactly what you've asked for) and modifying it to do what you want; if you only want to perform the `sub()` for a given set of hostnames then move it down inside the first `if`, eg, `if ((host==...)||(...)||(...)) { sub(...); if (ip in plans ...) printf ... } else if {....} else {...}`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think I found the way to reach what I want with real data. I'll inform you if needed help.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
                        if (ip in plans && c[2] == plans[ip])                  # if current ip is an index in plans[] array, and current plan name matches the plan name stored in plans[ip] ...
                            ip=gsub(/AIPlan/,"Plan")
                            printf "%s == %s\n%s == %s\n", ip, ip, c[2], c[2]   # print the desired output
```

to

```
                        if (ip in plans && c[2] == plans[ip]) {             # if current ip is an index in plans[] array, and current plan name matches the plan name stored in plans[ip] ...
                            gsub(/AIPlan/,"Plan", c[2])
                        }
                        printf "%s == %s\n%s == %s\n", ip, ip, c[2], c[2]   # print the desired output
```

Give a third argument to `gsub()` to specify where the replacement should be done. And don't reassign `ip` when you do this.

Comment: Thanks, I edited but nothing changes: `AIPlan BGP40 == AIPlan BGP40`.

Comment: `c[2] == plans[ip]` is never true. `c[2]` is `AIPlan BGP40`, but `plans[ip]` is just `Plan BGP40`

Comment: Nothing in the description of the task mentions comparing the plan names in the two files. It just says to replace `AIPlan` or `IAPlan` with `Plan`. So it's not clear why that condition exists in the script.